# How to input floating tone of African languages in LaTex?

Tags: tipa

I am inputting TIPA code for some African languages. I encountered a problem with inputting floating tone. The floating tone is a high tone (\') or a low tone (`) over a space instead of over any symbol.

If I input \'{ } or `{ }, the tone symbols drop to the bottom of the line, while they are supposed to be above the space. How can I deal with this problem? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tipa} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{IPA} 
aa\'{ } aa`{ } 
\end{IPA} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

For the high tone you can use: `\textceltpal`

For the low tone you can use: `\textquoteleft`

So to adjust your [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tipa} 
\begin{document} 

Instead of:

    \begin{IPA} 
        aa\'{ } aa`{ } 
    \end{IPA} 

You can use:

    \begin{IPA} 
        aa \textceltpal aa \textquoteleft 
    \end{IPA} 

\end{document}
```

edit: Used advice from  [barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton)

Comment: Can you please add a MWE?  Good answers should provide a MWE to give the op (and other readers) an easy way to proof the solution ...

Comment: i think you want to leave an explicit space between the two example strings.

Comment: Thank you! The     \textceltpal     might work. But I do not think    \textquoteleft  produces the same tone mark as  \'{ } does.  \'{ } is an acute accent (representing a high tone) according to TIPA, while  \textquoteleft produces a reversed apostrophe (representing week aspiration).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is surprisingly simple!

If you provide an argument to `\'` or the like, it will measure that character to decide where to put the accent.

But if you provide no argument, it gives you a "floating" diacritic.

```
a\'{}a\`{}a
```

Output: [image: output of the above]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\begin{IPA}
\LARGE{}a\'{}a\`{}a
\end{IPA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\LARGE` does not take an argument like that. The correct usage would be `{\LARGE a\'{}a\`{}a\par}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Oops, my mistake. Curiously, it gives the same result either way.

Comment: Yes, it does give the same result in this case. However try `\LARGE{This should be LARGE} and this should not` and then `{\LARGE This should be LARGE} and this should not` to see the difference.